How to move a shape on cairo surface by GtkEventControllerScroll (scroll event)?
I am trying to move a shape(circle) on GtkDrawingArea by scroll event(GtkEventControllerScroll). I tried the following code, but it is not working. I tried to move it only horizontally. The default horizontal position is 10, how to change value up and down by scroll event?? Can anyone check it?
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int pos = 10;

static void
draw_function (GtkDrawingArea *darea,
                     cairo_t        *cr,
                     int             width,
                     int             height,
                     gpointer        user_data)
{
  cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 0, 0, 0);
  cairo_paint (cr);

  cairo_set_source_rgb (cr, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
  cairo_set_line_width (cr, 1.5);
  cairo_arc (cr, pos, 10, 4, 0.0, 2 * G_PI);
  cairo_stroke (cr); 
}

static gboolean
_scroll_controller_scroll (GtkEventControllerScroll *scroll,
                                   gdouble                    x,
                                   gdouble                    y,
                                   gpointer                *widget)
{
    g_print("%d %d\n", x, y);
    pos = (int)x;
    gtk_widget_queue_draw ((GtkWidget *)widget);
}



static void
activate (GtkApplication* app,
          gpointer        user_data)
{
  GtkWidget *window = gtk_application_window_new (app);
  gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Color");
  gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 300, 200);

  GtkWidget *dr = gtk_drawing_area_new ();
  gtk_window_set_child ((GtkWindow   *)window, dr);
  gtk_drawing_area_set_content_width (GTK_DRAWING_AREA (dr), 300);
  gtk_drawing_area_set_content_height (GTK_DRAWING_AREA (dr), 200);
  gtk_drawing_area_set_draw_func (GTK_DRAWING_AREA (dr),
                                  draw_function,
                                  NULL, NULL);

  GtkEventController *controller = gtk_event_controller_scroll_new (GTK_EVENT_CONTROLLER_SCROLL_HORIZONTAL | 
                                                                    GTK_EVENT_CONTROLLER_SCROLL_BOTH_AXES);
  gtk_widget_add_controller (dr, GTK_EVENT_CONTROLLER (controller));
  gtk_event_controller_set_propagation_phase (controller, GTK_PHASE_CAPTURE);
  g_signal_connect (controller, "scroll", G_CALLBACK (_scroll_controller_scroll), dr);


  gtk_window_present (GTK_WINDOW (window));
}


int
main (int    argc,
      char **argv)
{
  GtkApplication *app;
  int status;
  app = gtk_application_new ("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE); 
  g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);
  status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
  g_object_unref (app);

  return status;
}


I found a solution to this question, so sharing. I made some mistake in the above code. Let me know if there is a better alternative answer.

Inside the function _scroll_controller_scroll replaced pos = (int)x; with pos = pos - (float)y;
Removed GTK_EVENT_CONTROLLER_SCROLL_HORIZONTAL | from the main function.

